# Bootstrap switch button event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap switch button. I want to change input value when on text or off text is changed. How can I check if on-text="Android" I want to print android to inp1 text or if off-text="IOS" I want to print ios to inp1 text. İs there another way to check text? You can check online demo http://jsfiddle.net/PNU45/156/

**HTML**

```
  <input type="input" id="inp1" value="">
  <input type="input" id="inp2" value="">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="true" class="alert-status" id="btn1" data-size="normal" name="my-checkbox" data-on-text="Android" data-off-text="IOS">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="true" class="alert-status" id="btn2" data-size="normal" name="my-checkbox" data-on-text="Java" data-off-text="C#">
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.alert-status').bootstrapSwitch('state', true);
$('#btn1').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
    var x=$(this).data('on-text');
    var y=$(this).data('off-text');
    if(x=="Android"){
        $("#inp1").val("Android");
    }
    if(y=="IOS"){
        $("#inp1").val("IOS");
    }
});
$('#btn2').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
    var x=$(this).data('on-text');
    var y=$(this).data('off-text');
    if(x=="Java"){
        $("#inp2").val("Java");
    }
    if(y=="IOS"){
        $("#inp2").val("IOS");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check if input is checked:

```
$('#switch').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
    var x = $(this).data('on-text');
    var y = $(this).data('off-text');
    if($("#switch").is(':checked')) {
      $("#in0p1").val(x);
    } else {
      $("#inp1").val(y);
    }
});

$('#switch2').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
    var x = $(this).data('on-text');
    var y = $(this).data('off-text');
    if($("#switch2").is(':checked')) {
      $("#inp2").val(x);
    } else {
      $("#inp2").val(y);
    }
});
```

### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PNU45/157/)

Comment: Thank you so much. You are really perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(selector).bootstrapSwitch('state');` to get the status of the switch

```
$('.alert-status').bootstrapSwitch('state', true);    
$(document).on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', '.alert-status', function (event, state) {
    if ($(this).bootstrapSwitch('state')) {     
         console.log($(this).data('on-text'));
    }else {
            console.log($(this).data('off-text'));
    }
});
```