# bootstrap-switch - trigger event when toggled

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have installed [bootstrap-switch](https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch) on a page to replace a HTML checkbox with a toggle element.

The replacement works well, but I have an issue getting the code syntax correct to trigger a function when the checkbox is changed / toggled.

I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043118/bootstrap-switch-button-event), but my code skills are not so great that I can solve this issue.

Here is my current code that works when I do not install the [bootstrap-switch](https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch) code on the `getAddressDetailsFormValues` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ....
    $('#id_address_style_one_line').bootstrapSwitch({'labelWidth': '5px', 'offText': '{% trans "No" %}', 'onText': '{% trans "Yes" %}', 'size': 'mini'});
    ....
});

function getAddressDetailsFormValues() {
    return {
        ....
        'address_style_one_line':
            ($('#id_display_address_on_one_line').is(':checked')) ?
                true:
                false,
        ....
    };
}
```

I have read the docs, but I cannot get the correct code syntax to trigger the change with the [bootstrap-switch](https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch) on the `getAddressDetailsFormValues` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the following:

```
($('#id_display_address_on_one_line').is(':checked')) ?
                true:
                false,
```

with:

```
$('#id_display_address_on_one_line').bootstrapSwitch('state')
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot.